# Proxy script manager for ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

We have proxy script manager asp:ScriptManagerProxy. with this i can use

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" />
//Master Page Data

//Content Page
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

My question is that, can i use reverse. 
i.e

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  AsyncPostBackTimeout="0"/>
```

in master page and some proxy of `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager` in content page